# Setup raid for a volume group consisting out of 2 nvme drives

Tags: ubuntu, raid, lvm

I bought 4 x 4tb nvme volumes.
I already tested them and they are doing fine.

Operating system is Ubuntu-server 23.04.

What i want to achieve is the following:

2 drives act as one. (I think that is a volume group)

On top i want the volume group to be mirrored to the other 2 drives that probably also need to be configured as a volume group. (that should be raid)

How to do that with lvm, volume-groups and mirroring devices?

Mount on startup should be doable with blkid + fstab and the id of the volume group. (Correct me if i am wrong)

Do i need to mount both groups in the fstab or are those no groups at all and i only need to mount one?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You basically want a RAID 10 using mdadm - just google that, there's loads of guides how to do it, but as @tsc_chazz states it gets complex with a boot drive

Answer (score 1):

Boot doesn't seem to work well with RAID, so I'd start by creating a small (5G) boot partition on one drive. On the remaining three, I'd be tempted to create a swap partition the same size, just for the sake of symmetry. Swap doesn't need to be RAIDed and generally shouldn't be.

RAID is at a lower level than logical volumes, so I'd first use `mdadm` to create either two RAID 1 arrays of two SSDs each, or a single RAID 10 array of 2x2 SSDs. If you've created a single RAID10 array, you're done; no need to go into LVM. Otherwise, you'd assign each of the two RAID arrays as a physical volume (PV), create a volume group (VG) that contains both, and then create a logical volume (LV) the full size of the volume group. You could then install a file system on the LV.